# UIWebView addSubView UIButton The button click event is not responding

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiwebview, uibutton

Here    _danView is Unbutton

and self is UIWebView

```
_danView.frame = CGRectMake(windowWidth +randWindth, gaodu+[heiArr[i]intValue], size.width+40+(size.height+8)/2, size.height+8);
_danView.backgroundColor = [UIColor colorWithPatternImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"danmaku_bg"]];
_danView.userInteractionEnabled = YES;
self.userInteractionEnabled = YES;
[_danView addTarget:self action:@selector(tapClick) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
_danView.layer.cornerRadius = (size.height+8)/2;
_danView.layer.masksToBounds = YES;
[self addSubview:_danView];
// [_danView addSubview:label];
[self animationWithView:_danView];


-(void)tapClick{

    NSLog(@"click click");

}
```

Answer (score 0):

UIWebView surely support addSubview for UIButton, so if it doesn't work, check the code.
I see you animate the button, how about remove the animation and test its click event, maybe you will find something the matter.

Comment: thank ，I tried to cancel the animation ，but the button still can not click

Comment: thank you，It is ok to open the webView.user interaction and  I remove the animation

Comment: But why not add animation？

Comment: Just because your code is no problem, so I guess the bug comes from animation. Surely it can add animation, maybe just your animation code has some bug. Maybe you have to paste up the animation code.

Answer (score -2):

use

```
- (IBAction)tapClick:(id)sender
```

instead of

```
-(void)tapClick
```